# Visual Force page help

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am trying to load values into VF input box  based on the account selected from popup.

```
          <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="pageblocksectionitem5">
         <apex:outputLabel value="Account Name"></apex:outputLabel>
         <apex:panelGroup style="border: 0px solid Blue;" > 
             <apex:outputPanel layout="inline" style="background-color:#CC0000; padding-left: 3px; position: absolute; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 2px; margin-right: 0px; height: 20px; border: 0px Red; " ></apex:outputPanel>                
             <input type="text" name="AccountName" id="Input12" style="margin-left: 5px; " /><img src="/s.gif" class="lookupIcon" onClick='window.open("/apex/xyz,"width=600,height=400,left=150,top=200,toolbar=1,status =1,");'/> 
         </apex:panelGroup>
     </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

     <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="pageblocksectionitem3">
          <apex:outputLabel value="Linea"></apex:outputLabel>
          <apex:outputLabel value="{!linea}"></apex:outputLabel>
      </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

I need to populate linea from  the custom field linea__c which is from Account object.. I can query to get the field value. But i need it to happen immediately after the account is selected. How can i do it?

Any pointers would be great...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need JavaScript actions... In fact probably best will be `action` and `rerender` attributes of most tags you'll see in the Visualforce Component Reference.

Please also have a look at this tutorial: http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Force.com_Tutorial:_An_Introduction_to_Visualforce, especially part above the "Tutorial: Web Applications In A Jiffy". Similar thing (restructured to form new Cookbook: http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/using-ajax-in-a-visualforce-page)

Last but not least - the [Visualforce Developer Guide](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Documentation#Apex_and_Visualforce) documentation PDF might be interesting for you - the chapter about "Creating a Wizard" (page 98 in the PDF) will be a nice (but a bit too full blown) example.